# Total Consumption Calculation for Multiple electric ovens

Tags: load, nec

Regarding NEC Table 220.55, if I have 4 ovens at 9 kW each, since they do not exceed 12 kW, I should refer to column C. However, my question is:

Is it correct to consider 17 kW as the total consumption? I reach this conclusion because I have 4 appliances, each with a total of 9 kW. Looking at the row for Number of Appliances = 4, column C indicates 17 kW.

Is that correct?

Comment: You might want to link to the publication, I'm not sure many people are going to go looking.